# what is use of base.OnManipulationStarted(e) in OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e) in C# .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I created a program which uses

```
OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
```

then I found

```
base.OnManipulationStarted(e)
```

which was automatically inserted in the code....I have commented that line and checked the program which gave no change in output of program..For what reason does this code exist in the default method ??

```
OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
```

Any help please...Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls the base class implementation of the method.

In particular, if you don't make that call, I wouldn't expect the [`ManipulationStartedEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted.aspx) to actually be raised. My guess is that you haven't seen any change in behaviour because nothing's subscribed to that event.

Unless you're *deliberately* suppressing the event (which sounds like a thoroughly bad idea to me) you should keep the base call.

Answer (score 1):

It calls base class' implementation of the method you're **[overriding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645768%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**. If you want to preserve base class behavior for `OnManipulationStarted`, you should leave that line in your overridden implementation.